# Brake bleeding without bleeding block

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

Is it ok to bleed my brake without a bleeding block and without removing the wheel?

What is the effect on the lever?
Will this result in a less firm lever?

Comment: Why would you not use a bleed block? You can make one out of just about anything, even a stick will do.

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended to bleed without removing the wheel as:

1. It is easy to contaminate your pads with spilt brake fluid
2. It is likely to result in overfilling your brake system. (resulting in pads not fully retracting and rubbing on disk).

You can make your own bleed block from common household items.
I followed the guide here:
http://www.epicbleedsolutions.com/blog/how-to-make-a-bleed-block/

Comment: Will it cause underfilling? Less firm lever?

Comment: No, a less firm lever is just a sign that you have not got all the air out of the system.  A bleed block should not make any difference here.

Comment: I see.. i tried to bleed my avid elixir 1. The bleed port on the lever is tilted to an angle, everytime i remove the syringe there will be leaks. With this i could not get a firm bleed. But the manual said its normal to leak. Any help?

Comment: Its quite normal for a tiny quantity of fluid to leak out when you remove the syringe, but if you replace the bleed port screw nice and quickly it will be fine.
Here is a nice step by step guide:
http://www.epicbleedsolutions.com/blog/how-to-bleed-avid-brakes-like-a-pro/

Comment: Avid Elixirs are a PITA to bleed. Sneaky tip , flip the bike onto its side each time to leave the port horizontal before unscrewing syringe. Top up to level with a bit of fluid and then re-screw port cap. The pressure lock on the calliper especially isn't usually enough to keep the chamber full before you can get the port screw back in.